# NSURLConnection Async Request and display a "Loading" alert view or subview while fulfilling request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to figure out the optimal way to perform an `NSURLConnection` Async Request and have the UI shielded with an alert view while the request is being fulfilled. I've had a lot of trouble getting this to work with a synchronous request because I could not figure out how to use the multi threading features or operation queues effectively with a synchronous request, so I figure this is the best way to go. Pseudo code or actual code is fine, I just need to know which direction to go. So far I figure:

- Create a `UIAlertView` property
- Create a void function that initiates the `NSURLConnection`, and display the view right after it initiates
- Use the delegate method to close the AlertView window `-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading` or something like that.

Is it this simple, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to do it is to use the UIApplication.networkActivityIndicatorVisible property, and do a sync request in a background thread.

```
-(void)loadURLInBackground:(NSURL*)url {

    NSURLRequest* req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10.0];

    NSURLResponse* response = nil;
    NSError* err = nil;

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;


    NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&response error:&err];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    if( data != nil ) { 
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(processData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:NO];
     } else {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(processError:) withObject:err waitUntilDone:NO];
     }
}
```

Use `[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadURLInBackground:) withObject:url];` to call the method, then just implement `processData:` and `processError:`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to use a UIAlertView - that is a modal dialog.

You want to use something like UIActivityIndicatorView to show the spinner while the background activity is going on.

Then, as you say, your delegate method can stopAnimating the activity indicator view.

If you want to show a message like "Downloading ...", then you can wrap your activity indicator inside another view, display that view, and remove it when the delegate calls back.